# Passing JavaScript Array to PHP giving Undefined Or Disallowed Key Characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have been struggling for a couple of days with this issue now. I have an array in JavaScript that I need to pass through to my PHP method.

My PHP:

```
public function saveCampaignSendToMediaOwner() {

    $result = $this->input->post();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
$('#saveCampaignSendToMediaOwner').on('click', function() {
console.log(allMediaOwnersObject);
for( var i = 0; i < allMediaOwnersObject.length; i++ ) {
    if( typeof(allMediaOwnersObject[i])==="undefined" ) {
        allMediaOwnersObject[i] = "";
    }
}
console.log(allMediaOwnersObject);
$.ajax({
    url: 'saveCampaignSendToMediaOwner',
    type: 'POST',
    data: allMediaOwnersObject,
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
});
```

The first `console.log(allMediaOwnersObject);` returns:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, ["8", "media owner", "developer", 6 more...]]
```

The second `console.log(allMediaOwnersObject);` returns:

```
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ["8", "media owner", "developer", 6 more...]]
```

Whenever I pass this variable to PHP, it returns:

```
<pre>Array
(
[undefined] => 
)
</pre>
```

And if I try change the `data` attribute in the AJAX to `{'mediaOwnersObject' : allMediaOwnersObject}` I get `Disallowed Key Characters`.

I have changed the `System/core/input.php`'s `_clean_input_keys` method to

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str)) {
        // there is no ~ in this regex pattern
        // You could add it, but you probably end up breaking other stuff ("/^[\w:~\/]+$/i")
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters');
    }
```

Why is this returning `undefined` in the PHP? This is the first time in the entire application that it is doing this, as all other AJAX and PHP methods ran flawlessly.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide your HTTP request headers ? (You can get them with the Firefox/Chrome developer tools, in the network tab)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'saveCampaignSendToMediaOwner',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {data : JSON.stringify(allMediaOwnersObject)},
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```